# How to get an username for firebase android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I've created a Chat function on my android app, but I wanted my users to be able to create an account. However, I managed to let users create an account using Firebase. But the problem is that it allows you to create accounts with Facebook etc, I choose for email and password. This doesn't allow you to set an username, I believe so. Maybe there's a way to change the UID?

If anyone is able to help me out here, I'd be so thankful!

Again, I'm trying to let the user create an username too.

Comment: I've tried making another form for it, created a username form, tried to code it aswell, but that didn't work, nothing really happened.. Thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [FirebaseUI implementation of its Email+Password registration flow](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/auth/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/auth/ui/email/RegisterEmailActivity.java#L145-L181):

```
firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
  .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
      if (task.isSuccessful()) {
        final FirebaseUser firebaseUser = task.getResult().getUser();
        Task<Void> updateTask = firebaseUser.updateProfile(
          new UserProfileChangeRequest
              .Builder()
              .setDisplayName(name).build());
        updateTask.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
          @Override
          public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            mActivityHelper.dismissDialog();
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
              startSaveCredentials(firebaseUser, password);
            }
          }
        });
      }
```

Alternatively, you might simple want to *use* FirebaseUI, which encapsulates this and many other auth flows.

Comment: I've downloaded the sample of how they would do it, I edited a bit of the code for my needs, but they don't really explain how to use an username

Comment: Maybe that depends on what you mean by "username". Firebase Authentication has the concept of a "display name", which for me would be "Frank van Puffelen". If that is what you're looking for, use `setDisplayName()`/`getDisplayName()`. If that's not what you're looking for, you'll have to be a bit more specific in your question about what you're aiming to do and what you've already tried.

Comment: I've tried using Displayname, but it doesn't show any name because the account you create only requires an email and password. If you know a way how to set / get a name, that would be appreciated!

Comment: The code I posted shows how to set a display name. Getting it is done by calling [`FirebaseUser.getDisplayName()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser.html#exceptions).

Comment: Okay, thank you very much. Unfortunately I'm not around my laptop right now, so I'll look into it tomorrow! If any problems occur, I'll contact you, if that's okay with you though.

Comment: It worked, thank you very much. Firebase is the best!